# WHy does GHC have problems with recursion during IO?

Tags: haskell

```
guessOneToTen :: IO ()
guessOneToTen = 
    forever (do
        number <- newNumber
        guessed <- firstPrompt
        untilM (== number) (const prompt) guessed
        correct)
    where
        newNumber = newStdGen >>= randomR (1, 10) >>= return . fst 
        readLine = getLine >>= return . read
        firstPrompt = putStr "Guess what number I am thinking of: " >> readLine
        prompt = putStr "Sorry try again: " >> readLine
        correct = putStrLn "You guessed correct!"
        untilM :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a
        untilM p f x
            | p x = return ()
            | otherwise = f x >>= untilM p f
```

This fails with

```
baby.hs:804:43:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = t0 -> IO a0
    In the third argument of `untilM', namely `guessed'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        untilM (== number) (const prompt) guessed
    In the first argument of `forever', namely
      `(do { number <- newNumber;
             guessed <- firstPrompt;
             untilM (== number) (const prompt) guessed;
             correct })'

baby.hs:807:35:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO a0'
                with actual type `(a1, StdGen)'
    Expected type: StdGen -> IO a0
      Actual type: StdGen -> (a1, StdGen)
    In the return type of a call of `randomR'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `randomR (1, 10)'

baby.hs:813:9:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `a -> m ()'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            untilM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a
          at baby.hs:813:9
    The equation(s) for `untilM' have three arguments,
    but its type `(a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a' has only two
    In an equation for `guessOneToTen':
        guessOneToTen
          = forever
              (do { number <- newNumber;
                    guessed <- firstPrompt;
                    untilM (== number) (const prompt) guessed;
                    correct })
          where
              newNumber = newStdGen >>= randomR (1, 10) >>= return . fst
              readLine = getLine >>= return . read
              firstPrompt
                = putStr "Guess what number I am thinking of: " >> readLine
              prompt = putStr "Sorry try again: " >> readLine
              ....

baby.hs:815:42:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `a -> m ()'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            untilM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a
          at baby.hs:813:9
    Expected type: (a -> m ()) -> Bool
      Actual type: a -> Bool
    In the first argument of `untilM', namely `p'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `untilM p f'

baby.hs:815:44:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `a -> m ()'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            untilM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a
          at baby.hs:813:9
    Expected type: (a -> m ()) -> m (a -> m ())
      Actual type: a -> m a
    In the second argument of `untilM', namely `f'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `untilM p f'

baby.hs:815:44:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `a -> m ()'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            untilM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a
          at baby.hs:813:9
    Expected type: (a -> m ()) -> m (a -> m ())
      Actual type: a -> m a
    In the second argument of `untilM', namely `f'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `untilM p f'
```

I don't understand why.  Can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you're using `randomR` wrong. Its type is `randomR :: RandomGen g => (a, a) -> g -> (a, g)`, so there's no monads involved, yet you're using it with the monadic bind operator `(>>=)`. You'll also have to add a type signature to specify just what number type you want a random of.

We can change it to this.

```
newNumber = newStdGen >>= return . fst . randomR (1, 10) :: IO Int
```

However, there is no need to get a new generator each time. We can simplify this by using the one provided by `IO`.

```
newNumber = randomRIO (1, 10) :: IO Int
```

Secondly, your type signature for `untilM` is wrong. We can just omit it and let the compiler infer the correct type, which in this case is

```
untilM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m ()
```

Also, you don't have to define `readLine`. It already exists in the Prelude with the name `readLn`.

Putting this all together, we get this working code.

```
guessOneToTen :: IO ()
guessOneToTen = 
    forever (do
        number <- newNumber
        guessed <- firstPrompt
        untilM (== number) (const prompt) guessed
        correct)
    where
        newNumber = randomRIO (1, 10) :: IO Int
        firstPrompt = putStr "Guess what number I am thinking of: " >> readLn
        prompt = putStr "Sorry try again: " >> readLn
        correct = putStrLn "You guessed correct!"
        untilM :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m ()
        untilM p f x
            | p x = return ()
            | otherwise = f x >>= untilM p f
```